# Efficiently check if path is valid in graph using NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, automata

I would like to find an efficient way to check if a given "Walk" through a graph is valid.

Such a function should accept a Graph (nodes, edges) and a string of node names, and should output True if nodes can be visited in the given sequence according to the graph and false if not.

Preferably, I would use the NetworkX library, since I already use it to store and represent the graph.

Something resembling this:

```
""" G:
    Q1 -> Q1
    Q1 -> Q2
    Q2 -> Q2
"""
accepts(G, ["Q1", "Q1", "Q2"]) 
>> True
accepts(G, ["Q2", "Q2", "Q2"]) 
>> True
accepts(G, ["Q2", "Q2", "Q1"]) 
>> False
accepts(G, ["Q1", "Q2", "Q1"]) 
>> False
accepts(G, ["Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q1"]) 
>> False
```

This would be used for a automata class. To basically check for membership of a string given a language represented by the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @newbie's sentiment that "You only need to check if all the edges of the path are valid" is correct, the implementation he gives is far from efficient; `graph.edges()` rebuilds a list of all the graph's edges from scratch for every edge in the path. Instead of `(u, v) in g.edges()` you should always use `g.has_edge(u, v)`, which is a constant-time operation. Although it seems you're working with `DiGraph` at the moment, the latter method also has the added benefit of working for both `Graph` and `DiGraph`, while the earlier method only works for `DiGraph`. (This is because a `Graph`'s `edges()` method only returns the edges in one (random) direction, so checking for the edge in one direction only does not suffice; `g.has_edge()` does the right thing here for both `Graph` and `DiGraph`)

Long story short, use:

```
def accepts(g, path):
    return all([g.has_edge(path[i], path[i+1]) for i in range(len(path)-1)])
```

Or, a bit more concisely:

```
def accepts(g, path):
    return all(map(g.has_edge, path, path[1:]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check if all the edges of the path are valid.

```
def accepts(g, path):
    return all([(path[i],path[i+1]) in g.edges() for i in range(len(path)-1)])
```

Example:

```
g=nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge("Q1","Q1")
g.add_edge("Q1","Q2")
g.add_edge("Q2","Q2")

print(accepts(g, ["Q1", "Q1", "Q2"]))
print(accepts(g, ["Q2", "Q2", "Q2"]))
print(accepts(g, ["Q2", "Q2", "Q1"]))
print(accepts(g, ["Q1", "Q2", "Q1"]))
print(accepts(g, ["Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q1"]))
```